# Поиск max и min значений

Tags: javascript

На входе у меня строка чисел. Нужно найти максимальное и минимальное значение. Не воспринимается число 0. Что не так сделал?)

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  var arr = numbers.split(" ").map(Number).filter(Boolean);
  var largest = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  var least = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  var answer = `${largest} ${least}`;
  return answer;
}

console.log(highAndLow("1 0")); //?
console.log(highAndLow("0 -1 ")); //? 
console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
```

Comment: "Не воспринимается" - куда?

Comment: А вы понимаете зачем вы написали filter(Boolean)?

Comment: Если выполнить данный код, то в консоль выводит неправильно в первых двух вариантах. (1 1 вместо 1 0 и -1 -1 вместо 0 -1)

Comment: чтобы исключить из диапазона входящих данных строки и т.д. ("1 0 ыфв фыв %")

Comment: У меня для вас новость: 0 это тоже false и вы его только что исключили

Comment: согласен, только учусь)

Comment: Скорее стоит использовать Number.isFinite или даже Number.isInteger раз у вас только целые числа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем Вы написали `.filter(Boolean);`, и что *оно* по-Вашему делает?

Посмотрим, что получается после фильтрации:

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  var arr = numbers.split(" ").map(Number).filter(Boolean);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
  /*var largest = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  var least = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  var answer = `${largest} ${least}`;
  return answer;*/
}

highAndLow("1 0");
highAndLow("0 -1 ");
highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6");
```

---

Чтобы отсеять "нечисла":

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  var arr = numbers.split(" ").map(Number).filter(e => !isNaN(e));
  var largest = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  var least = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  var answer = `${largest} ${least}`;
  return answer;
}

console.log(highAndLow("1 abc 0")); //?
console.log(highAndLow("0 -1 ")); //? 
console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  var arr = numbers.split(" ").map(el => +el).filter(el => el != 0);
  var largest = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  var least = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  var answer = `${largest} ${least}`;
  return answer;
}

console.log(highAndLow("1 0")); //?
console.log(highAndLow("0 -1 ")); //? 
console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
```